# Extract the last characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the last two digits in a string. First I remove any spaces or special characters and replace them with a hyphen then if there are two hyphens following each other, I remove them. ext I remove any trailing hyphens. Next I want to extract the last two characters after the lat hyphen in the string. For example how do I extract the last characters in this string i.e `1` after the last hyphen? `awesome-page-1`. My code is here

```
$string = 'awesome page@1';
  $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', $string);//replace spaces and special characters with space
        $slug = preg_replace('#-{2,}#', '-', $slug);//two hyphens following each other
        $slug = trim($slug, '-');//remove trailing hyphens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strrchr()` to find the last dash in the created slug and then skip past that using `substr()`.

```
$slug = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', $string), '-');

echo substr(strrchr($slug, '-'), 1);
```

*If there are no dashes in `$string`, the result will be empty*

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LINBKG)

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays as param for `preg_replace`;

```
$str  = 'awesome            page........@1';
$slug = preg_replace(
    array('~[^a-zA-Z0-9-]~', '~-+~'),
    '-',
    trim($str)
);
print $slug; // awesome-page-1

preg_match('~-([^-]*)$~', $slug, $m);
print $m[1]; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you only want to match if the last characters after the hyphen are digits:

```
$slug = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '-', $string), '-');
if (preg_match('/^.*-(\d+)$/', $slug, $matches)) {                                                                                               
    echo $matches[1];                                                                
} else {                                                                             
    echo 'No Match!';                                                                
}
```